# Where to see all Mathematica units

Tags: units

Is there a tutorial page that have all Mathematica units? I sometimes have hard time figuring out the correct unit spelling when using quantities

Comment: You could check out: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Units.html

Comment: You can use a query to WolframAlpha to discover units for a particular application, e.g., `WolframAlpha["units for volume"]` or `WolframAlpha["SI units"]`

Comment: also of note: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/Units.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This should list you all available units in Mathematica.

```
Needs["QuantityUnits`"]    
Keys[QuantityUnits`Private`$UnitReplacementRules]
```

Inspired by **eldo** I made a little dynamic interface:

```
Needs["QuantityUnits`"]
table = Keys[QuantityUnits`Private`$UnitReplacementRules];

Panel[DynamicModule[{f = ""}, 
  Column[{Text[Style["Mathematica Unit Search:", Bold]], 
    InputField[Dynamic[f], String, ContinuousAction -> True], 
    Dynamic[Union@Flatten[StringCases[#, ___ ~~ f ~~ ___] & /@ table] // 
      TableForm]}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Notice the typo: "FeetfRainfall" (reported to Support)

Comment: That panels make Mathematica 10 crash if pressing "panel format" in the suggestion bar. Can anybody confirm that please?

Comment: Can confirm! (Windows 7 64-bit, MMA10)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I'm Not in front of a proper computer now, I will file a report in a few hours unless somebody else does it before me.

Comment: Do that! Funny how this answer revealed a typo and a bug.

Comment: Here it is: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58868

Answer (score 12):

Expanding a little bit on **paw**'s nice discovery:

```
Needs["QuantityUnits`"]    
table = Keys[QuantityUnits`Private`$UnitReplacementRules];
```

Since this table is very long one can restrict the output, f.e. with

```
Union @ Flatten[StringCases[#, "Feet" ~~ ___] & /@ table] // TableForm
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

A similar question could arise with the more than 1000 inbuilt formula names:

```
formulas = FormulaLookup[All];
```

Find all formulas including "speed":

```
(speed =
   Union@Flatten[
     StringCases[#, ___ ~~ "speed" ~~ ___, IgnoreCase -> True] & /@
      formulas]) // Multicolumn
```

[image]

Extract those with `FormulaData`:

```
(inter = Intersection[FormulaData[], speed]) // Multicolumn
```

[image]

```
TraditionalForm@
 Framed[Grid[{#, FormulaData[#]} & /@ inter,
   Dividers -> All,
   Spacings -> {{2, 2}, 3},
   Alignment -> Left,
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica"},
   Background -> {None, {{Hue[.6, .15, .9], GrayLevel[.9]}}},
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, White]
   ],
  FrameMargins -> 0.5,
  FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[.7]]
```

[image]