# Dynamic panel crashes Mathematica 10.0.0.0

Tags: bugs, dynamic, gui-construction, crash, predictive-interface

This [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58794/10397) by @paw have revealed a bug that causes Mathematica v 10.0.0.0 to crash the GUI and kernel. So far the offending code is this:

```
Needs["QuantityUnits`"]
table = Keys[QuantityUnits`Private`$UnitReplacementRules];

Panel[DynamicModule[{f = ""}, 
  Column[{Text[Style["Mathematica Unit Search:", Bold]], 
    InputField[Dynamic[f], String, ContinuousAction -> True], 
    Dynamic[Union@Flatten[StringCases[#, f ~~ ___] & /@ table] // 
      TableForm]}]]]
```

This creates a dynamic panel and the crash happens when pressing "panel format" in the suggestion bar. The bug has been confirmed so far only on M10 under Windows 7 64 bits.

My skills are not enough to reduce that code to a minimum working example that reproduces the crash, nor I have available Mathematica under other OS. So I'm both reporting the bug and asking:

1. What would be a minimum working example of the crash?
2. Does this crash also in other platforms?

The Wolfram Technical Support identification code is: CASE:1566616

Comment: I don't see a "panel format" item in the suggestion bar using version 10.0.1 under Windows.  Perhaps this has been fixed, or at least circumvented?

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that this occurs (using the above code and clicking "panel format…") using Mathematica v.10.0.0 on OS X 10.9.4 (64-bit). I can't provide any further help on the MWE for this, as I'm still learning to use MMA as a coding language, rather than a fancy CAS.

I've uploaded a copy of the OS X crash log [here](https://gist.github.com/06d421d3859e06f97918).

#### EDIT:

As [Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58868/dynamic-panel-crashes-mathematica-10-0-0-0#comment170851_58868) observed, this doesn't occur with 10.0.1 (on OS X 10.9.5) since the option "Panel format" never appears as a suggestion.