# How to obtain a complete list of WordData's "Properties"?

Tags: curated-data, documentation, undocumented, properties

Command `WordData["Word", "Properties"]` seems to return an endless list of properties, such as:

`"Definitions"`, `"PartsOfSpeech"`, `"Definitions"`, `"Examples"`, `"Synonyms"`, `"Antonyms"`, `"BroaderTerms"`, `"NarrowerTerms"`, `"ConceptWeight"`, `"BritishSpelling"`, `"AmericanSpelling"`...

Is it possible obtain a complete list of it?

Comment: This is related, bot not the same, as this question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58793/10397

Comment: Isn't that a complete list of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complete list can be obtained using

```
WordData["Properties"]
```

or using

```
WordData["anyword","Properties"]

WordData["Properties"] // Row[#, " \[CenterDot] "] &
```

[image]

Note: `ElementData`, `ColorData`, `CountryData`, `CityData`,  `ChemicalData`, etc.,  work similarly.