# How can I make a summary of all the commands of Mathematica?

Tags: syntax, core-language, symbols

I would like to have a simple way to get summary information about all the many commands built into *Mathematica*. How could I do this? Is there a site I may refer to?

Comment: According to the Wolfram Research site *Mathematica* currently has more than 5000 built-in functions (which is probably what you mean by "commands"). What would you do with a list of 5000 function names if you had one? In desperation you could evaluate `Information["*"]`.This will give you information on the most readily available functions, but also lists symbols that are not functions.

Comment: Listing of all symbols  and functions as of V9 is [here](http://12000.org/my_notes/compare_mathematica/V9/main.html) V10 listing has not been updated due to some problems with the current script running on V10. Alphabetical listing of all commands/symbols is [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/AlphabeticalListing.html) and with description is [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/alphaindex/A.html)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I would like to draw your attention to one more Post: [Where to see all Mathematica units (duplicate)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58793/where-to-see-all-mathematica-units/58797#58797)

Answer (score 6):

In 10.2 there is `WolframLanguageData`.

As a sample, to get a list (sorted by common-ness) of symbols which do not begin with $, are not *Box or *Data functions, are not solely options to other functions, and having got rid of some of the display-only things like `AngleBracket`:

```
dat = WolframLanguageData[
 All,
 {"CanonicalName", "Frequencies", "PlaintextUsage"}];

pruned = Cases[dat, Except[{_, _Missing, _}]];

firstWordInUsage[s_String] := 
 If[StringContainsQ[s, "]"], 
  ReadList[StringToStream@
   StringTake[s, StringPosition[s, "]"][[1, 1]] + 2 ;;], 
   Word][[1]],
  ReadList[StringToStream@s, Word][[2]]]

pruned2 = 
 Cases[pruned, 
  Except@{_, _, _String?({"displays"}~MemberQ~
     firstWordInUsage[#] &)}];

pruned3 = 
 Cases[pruned2, 
  Except@{_, _, _String?(ReadList[StringToStream[#], 
       Word][[2 ;; 4]] == {"is", "an", "option"} &)}];

pruned4 = 
 Select[pruned3, 
  Not@StringEndsQ[#[[1]], "Box"] && 
  Not@StringEndsQ[#[[1]], "Data"] &];

pruned5 = Select[pruned4, Not@StringStartsQ[#[[1]], "$"] &];

final = MapAt["All" /. # &, pruned5, {All, 2}][[All, 1 ;; 2]];

First /@ SortBy[final, -# &@*Last]
```

You may access the plaintext usage with `EntityValue[#, "PlaintextUsage"]&` applied to the appropriate `Entity` object.

Comment: Caveat: it misses `UnitBox[]` and `SeriesData[]`.

Comment: True, thanks - I just grabbed some rough-and-ready heuristics.

Comment: It's a bit weird that WolframLanguageData downloads the whole dataset every time I use it, instead of caching it like some *data functions used to do.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a list of all built-in commands, just type:

```
Names["System`*"]
```

If you want all the information of them:

```
Information/@Names["System`*"]
```

Comment: Not every System symbol has an information message.  To limit it one may choose to use something like my answer below. +1

Answer (score 4):

The *official* list of defined Symbols is here:

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/AlphabeticalListing.html

You can find the usage message for all `` System` `` Symbols that have one with:

```
msg = MakeExpression@# /. _[x_] :> MessageName[x, "usage"] &;

Cases[msg /@ Names["System`*"], _String]
```

Warning: it is slow.

Answer (score 1):

```
Flatten @ Names[#] & /@ (StringJoin[#, "*"] & /@ CharacterRange["A", "Z"])
```